# What is the Solution to this sum $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})(\frac{1}{2})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

what is the value of this series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})(\frac{1}{2})^n$   ?

Anything what's solid and that i got so far is only

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})(\frac{1}{2})^n$ = $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-i^{n^2+n})(\frac{1}{2})^n$

and that the right part reminds me of the geometric series

Comment: Do not use the imaginary unit. Try to write out the first few terms. What do you get?

Comment: Hint: Note that$$(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{4} \\ 2 & \text{ if } n \equiv 1,2 \pmod{4}\end{cases}$$

Comment: See @AnuragA ‘s comment

Comment: Suppose you understand AnuragA’s hint, but still don’t know how to evaluate the series. Now, just note that the skipped (coefficient = 0) terms are just a shifted version of the non-skipped (coefficient = 2) terms. But shifted by 2 simply means differing by a factor of 2^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{4} \\ 2 & \text{ if } n \equiv 1,2 \pmod{4}\end{cases}$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n&=\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}0+\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}+\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}+\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}0\\
&= \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\\
&= 2\left(\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Now we just have to focus on these geometric series. For example,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\{\small n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^9}+\dotsb\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2^4}}\\
&=\frac{8}{15}.
\end{align*}
Hopefully you can complete now.